# Calculate the number of hexes between two hexes on a hex grid?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, hexagonal-tiles

[image]

Using the hexgrid and coordinates above, I am trying to find a consistent formula to calculate the distance between two hexes.

Comment: Also, have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565993/4294399

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched from my x,y to q,r,s coordinates by

```
q=x
r=y-(x+(ISODD(x)))/2
s=-r-q
```

then used this formula:

```
=max(abs(q1-q2) + abs(r1-r2) + abs(s1-s2)) / 2
```

hopefully this helps someone using an even-q grid